# Can I enable AMD freesync using the amdgpu driver via HDMI in 20.04?

Tags: graphics, hdmi, 20.04, amdgpu

[Here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-754) it says it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This I dont know but I have still same trouble with AMD drivers like on 19.04. The driver amdgpu is sometime loaded and sometime it doesnt load and I can see only black screen.

Restarts helped and for example one per 5 restart amdgpu is loaded and GPU is working correctly.

HP EliteBook 745 G5 
AMD Ryzen 3 PRO 2300U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx